# Is their any way to convert .jpeg images to .gif in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video, jpeg

Like my title, is there anyway to convert images to a video in flutter? (It doesn't have to be .gif necessarily)

To be more specific, I am using Google Firebase as my storage cloud server to upload pictures taken by camera plugin of flutter.

I want to convert my images to a video so that it looks like a time-lapse video.
Any advice would be nice.

===============================

the pictures are taken by camera plugin which uses camera.dart, and it is stored it firebase storage like this:

```
onCapture(context) async {
try {
  final p = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  var now = DateTime.now();
  var formattedDate = DateFormat('yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(now);
  final path = '${p.path}/$now.png';
  await cameraController.takePicture(path).then((value) {
    print('here');
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PreviewScreen(
                  imgPath: path,
                  fileName: '$formattedDate.png',
                  pickedTime: '$formattedDate',
                )));
  });
} catch (e) {
  showCameraException(e);
 }
}
```

========================================

edit :
Before constructing gif, i am having trouble downloading an image from firebase and putting this image on the canvas. I think I can use your code to make a gif once I do this.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as IMG;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' as firebase_core;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:weighit/models/user_info.dart';

class ToGif extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Timelapse Video'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Thumbnail(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Thumbnail extends StatefulWidget {
  const Thumbnail({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ThumbnailState createState() => _ThumbnailState();
}

class _ThumbnailState extends State<Thumbnail> {
  List<int> imgBytes;
  Isolate isolate;
  File image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _asyncInit();

    super.initState();
  }

  static _isolateEntry(dynamic d) async {
    final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
    d.send(receivePort.sendPort);

    final config = await receivePort.first;

    print(config);

    final file = File(config['path']);
    final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();

    IMG.Image image = IMG.decodeImage(bytes);
    IMG.Image thumbnail = IMG.copyResize(
      image,
      width: config['size'].width.toInt(),
    );

    d.send(IMG.encodeNamedImage(thumbnail, basename(config['path'])));
  }

  _asyncInit() async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();
    isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEntry, receivePort.sendPort);

    receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
      if (data is SendPort) {
        if (mounted) {
          data.send({
            'path': image.path,
            'size': Size(500, 500),
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            imgBytes = data;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (isolate != null) {
      isolate.kill();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Download on DocumnetDirectory, not temporary directory https://flutter-ko.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files
  Future<void> downloadFileExample() async {
    final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    image = File('${appDocDir.path}/download-logo.png');

    try {
      await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          // can not find proper reference path...
          .ref('gs://weighit-f506b.appspot.com/guny/21-04-26 10:56:21.png')
          .writeToFile(image);
    } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
      print('couldnt find the reference');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _user = Provider.of<TheUser>(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: downloadFileExample(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //해당 부분은 data를 아직 받아 오지 못했을때 실행되는 부분을 의미한다.
        if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        //error가 발생하게 될 경우 반환하게 되는 부분
        else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'Error: ${snapshot.error}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            child: imgBytes != null
                ? Image.memory(
                    imgBytes,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                : Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.grey[100], Colors.grey[300]],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add a code sample of what you have tried so far

Comment: @RachelGallen sorry for the late reply, it was my mid-term exam week so I didn't have time to check! I will show my code, but I don't have any code that converts images to .gif since I don't have any clue :(

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`image`](https://pub.dev/packages/image) package to created animated GIFs from multiple images.

First add it as a dependency:

```YAML
dependencies:
  image: ^3.0.2
```

Then to you can make a function to generate an animated GIF from multiple images:

```dart
List<int>? generateGIF(Iterable<Image> images) {
  final Animation animation = Animation();
  for(Image image in images) {
    animation.addFrame(image);
  }
  return encodeGifAnimation(animation);
}
```

To use this function with multiple images that are in files from the `camera` package in the form of `XFile`s, you have to decode the images for each of those files and pass it to this function. The following code assumes you know that these are JPEG images:

```dart
List<XFile> imageFiles = ...;

final JpegDecoder decoder = JpegDecoder();
final List<Image> images = [];
for(var imgFile in imageFiles) {
  Uint8List data = await imgFile.readAsBytes();
  images.add(decoder.decodeImage(data));
}

List<int>? gifData = generateGIF(images);
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea to implement timelapse video. But I tried your code, and it didn't work out well :( I am quite new to flutter, so I couldn't sought this out by myself

Comment: firstly, as I import images package to my dart file, it caused an 'ambiguous import' error on declaring Image type.
Declaring Animation class was also impossible due to ambiguous error. Also, Animation class is abstract class that couldn't be used... I tried my best to fix these errors but I couldn't help it

Comment: @JohnPark You need to import the library somewhere. Your IDE should be able to suggest the correct import, but here it is anyways `import 'package:image/image.dart';`

Comment: Thank you! i did that, and the problem was that there is another Image class included in material.dart. I fixed that problem by using 'as' prefix like 
      'import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;'

Comment: I have a new problem now... how do i get a path for image files??

Comment: @JohnPark What do you have so far? If you're getting it directly from the camera then you should be able to figure it out from the second block of code. If you're getting it from firebase storage, you need to download it as a `Uint8List` and put it into the second block of code in my answer.

Comment: Before generating gif, I am having trouble downloading an image from firebase and putting this on the canvas. I posted my code above :) I really appreciate your help

Comment: @JohnPark Please do not add additional information as answers. Please edit the code into the question and reduce it down as much as possible. You have code to download some firebase images. Make an attempt at downloading the data yourself and if you have problems, be as specific as possible.

Comment: sorry that I am also new to stackoverflow and I was lacking of basic manners..
I will do my best to find the solutions by myself. Beside that, your answer helped a lot!