# How to convert a List<Uint8list> to GIF?

Tags: flutter, dart, gif

How to convert `List<Uint8List>` to an animated GIF?

my `List<Uint8List>` consists of images and I need to merge them and make them as GIF.

I've tried this but it does not animate:
[Is their any way to convert .jpeg images to .gif in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160196/is-their-any-way-to-convert-jpeg-images-to-gif-in-flutter)

Comment: I think you need to add a duration for each frame , make it for example 20 .

Comment: I think that the best way to do is like @elvis-salabrarria-aquino says, with a external program, may be you can convert a video or sequence of images and do it from on it.

Comment: A few questions in regards to the requirements you have. 1) Uint8List - those are bytes clearly though it is not specified what exactly they store? A bitmap with certain pixel size and some headers specifying dimensions? A complete image file of known formats (e.g. PNG, JPG) or a single format? 2) Do you need to convert a list of bitmaps OR image files (previous question) to a GIF file which will have each list present as a frame? OR do you want to display the images in Flutter app as animated frames (i.e. present them as Video/Animated GIF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160196/is-their-any-way-to-convert-jpeg-images-to-gif-in-flutter) you provided should work. If not, please give a reproducible sample. For example, provide your sample `List<Uint8List>`. In addition, what error messages do you see?

Without further information, I guess your `Uint8List` is not of the correct format. If you upload one example Uint8List (you know, just some bytes), I can have a look.

By the way, I suggest to have some basic understanding of image formats. For example, what is a "bitmap" (pixels are arranged byte by byte), and what is a encoded format like jpeg/png/gif/etc.

Comment: btw you are correct my Uint8list format is just incorrect.

Comment: do you know how to parse List<int> to Uint8list?, because the function shown in the link provided is returning a List<int> instead of Uint8list. because I want to display the gif  in a Image.memory() widget

Comment: @AgentRed Uint8List.fromList(your_list)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing is that you develop the gif in any program for this and then load it with your app from the assets, if you need help tell me and I can help you better by sending me the images to make the gif