# converting images to gif in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, gif

im making a program that takes some photos and then convert them to a gif and then display it
i used the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160196/is-their-any-way-to-convert-jpeg-images-to-gif-in-flutter) but i cant make it work im getting some frustrating errors.

in this line `Image.memory( Uint8List.fromList( generateGIF(images)! ), )`

the error says that i cant put list of images into iterable of images

also the ide is getting frustrated between the two Image classes because im using the [Image Package](https://pub.dev/packages/image)
so that i named the package as imageGen i dont know if im using it write in this function

```
List<int>? generateGIF(Iterable<imageGen.Image> images) {
    final imageGen.Animation animation = imageGen.Animation();
    for(imageGen.Image image in images) {
      animation.addFrame( image );
    }
    return imageGen.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
  }
```

and this is my code

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:deaf_helper/logic/gif_generator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageGen ;
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

class FaceToFaceTab extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _FaceToFaceTabState createState() => _FaceToFaceTabState();
}

class _FaceToFaceTabState extends State<FaceToFaceTab> {
  final SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController() ;
  List images = [] ;
  GifGenerator generator = GifGenerator();
  bool start = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initSpeech();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _initSpeech() async {
    await _speechToText.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _startListening() async {
    await _speechToText.listen(
      onResult: _onSpeechResult,
      localeId: language,
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _stopListening() async {
    await _speechToText.stop();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
        textEditingController.text = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              color1,
              color2,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(48),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: start ? Image.memory( Uint8List.fromList( generateGIF(images)! ), ) : isArabic ? Text('اضغط على زر الأرسال') : Text('Press the send button') ,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                          setState((){
                            textEditingController.text = '';
                          });
                        },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close_outlined, color: color2,),
                        ),),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 11,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          textAlign: isArabic? TextAlign.right : TextAlign.left,
                          controller: textEditingController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: isArabic ? 'قم بالتسجيل او ابدأ الكتابه' : 'Start recording or start typing',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          start = true;
                          getSentencePictures(textEditingController.text);
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.send,size: 28, color: color2,),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: getMicIconBtn(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getMicIconBtn() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed:
        _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Record',
        icon: Icon(
          _speechToText.isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none,
          size: 40,
          color: color2,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<int>? generateGIF(Iterable<imageGen.Image> images) {
    final imageGen.Animation animation = imageGen.Animation();
    for(imageGen.Image image in images) {
      animation.addFrame( image );
    }
    return imageGen.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
  }

  getSentencePictures(String sentence){

    for(int x = 0 ; x < sentence.length ; x++){

      switch(sentence[x]){
        case 'a' :
        case 'A' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/a.png'),);
        break;
        case 'b' :
        case 'B' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/b.png'),);
        break;
        case 'c' :
        case 'C' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/c.png'),);
        break;
        case 'd' :
        case 'D' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/d.png'),);
        break;
        case 'e' :
        case 'E' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/e.png'),);
        break;
        case 'f' :
        case 'F' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/f.png'),);
        break;
        case 'g' :
        case 'G' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/g.png'),);
        break;
        case 'h' :
        case 'H' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/h.png'),);
        break;
        case 'i' :
        case 'I' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/i.png'),);
        break;
        case 'j' :
        case 'J' :images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/j.png'),);
        break;
        case 'k' :
        case 'K' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/k.png'),);
        break;
        case 'l' :
        case 'L' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/l.png'),);
        break;
        case 'm' :
        case 'M' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/m.png'),);
        break;
        case 'n' :
        case 'N' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/n.png'),);
        break;
        case 'o' :
        case 'O' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/o.png'),);
        break;
        case 'p' :
        case 'P' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/p.png'),);
        break;
        case 'q' :
        case 'Q' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/q.png'),);
        break;
        case 'r' :
        case 'R' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/r.png'),);
        break;
        case 's' :
        case 'S' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/s.png'),);
        break;
        case 't' :
        case 'T' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/t.png'),);
        break;
        case 'u' :
        case 'U' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/u.png'),);
        break;
        case 'v' :
        case 'V' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/v.png'),);
        break;
        case 'w' :
        case 'W' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/w.png'),);
        break;
        case 'x' :
        case 'X' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/x.png'),);
        break;
        case 'y' :
        case 'Y' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/y.png'),);
        break;
        case 'z' :
        case 'Z' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/z.png'),);
        break;
        case '0' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/zero.png'),);
        break;
        case '1' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/one.png'),);
        break;
        case '2' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/two.png'),);
        break;
        case '3' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/three.png'),);
        break;
        case '4' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/four.png'),);
        break;
        case '5' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/five.png'),);
        break;
        case '6' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/six.png'),);
        break;
        case '7' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/seven.png'),);
        break;
        case '8' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/eight.png'),);
        break;
        case '9' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/nine.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ا' :
        case 'أ' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/أ.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ب' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ب.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ت' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ت.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ث' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ث.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ج' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ج.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ح' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ح.png'),);
        break;
        case 'خ' :images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/خ.png'),);
        break;
        case 'د' :images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/د.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ذ' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ذ.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ر' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ر.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ز' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ز.png'),);
        break;
        case 'س' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/س.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ش' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ش.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ص' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ص.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ض' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ض.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ط' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ط.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ظ' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ظ.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ع' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ع.png'),);
        break;
        case 'غ' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/غ.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ف' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ف.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ق' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ق.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ك' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ك.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ل' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ل.png'),);
        break;
        case 'م' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/م.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ن' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ن.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ه' :
        case 'ة' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ه.png'),);
        break;
        case 'و' : images.add(Image.asset('assets/sign-lang/و.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ي' :
        case 'ى' : images.add(AssetImage('assets/sign-lang/ي.png'),);
        break;
        case 'ئ' : images.add(Image.asset('assets/sign-lang/ئ.png'),);
        break;
        default : images.add(Image.asset('assets/app_logo.png'),);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of iteraable change it to list

```dart
List<int>? generateGIF(List<imageGen.Image> images) {
    final imageGen.Animation animation = imageGen.Animation();
    for(imageGen.Image image in images) {
      animation.addFrame( image );
    }
    return imageGen.encodeGifAnimation(animation);
  }
```

Comment: i made it work earlier but thank you for your comment